# The C++ Standard doesn't provide a hash for this type. Help creating a suitable hash function

Tags: c++, hash

My code gives the error:

```
The C++ Standard doesn't provide a hash for this type.
```

From googling it seems that I need to create a hash function for my unordered_map's. I have a few ideas on how to create one but I don't know if it'll give the same hash for two different pairs. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <queue>
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct Graph{   //this will be the map
    typedef tuple<int, int> Location;   //basically an (x,y) coordinate
    static array<Location, 4> DIRS;

    unordered_set<Location>walls;

    int width, height;
    Graph(int width_, int height_) :width(width_), height(height_){}    //constructor

    inline bool in_bounds(Location id){ //make sure in bounds
        int x, y;
        tie(x, y) = id;
        return 0 <= x<width && 0 <= y<height;
    }

    inline bool passable(Location id){  //check if wall
        return !walls.count(id);
    }

    vector<Location> neighbors(Location id){    //return 4 neighbors
        int x, y, dx, dy;
        tie(x, y) = id;
        bool possible;
        vector<Location> results;
        for (auto dir : DIRS) {
            tie(dx, dy) = dir;
            Location next(x + dx, y + dy);
            if (in_bounds(next) && passable(next)) {
                results.push_back(next);
            }
        }
        if ((x + y) % 2 == 0) {
            // aesthetic improvement on square grids
            std::reverse(results.begin(), results.end());
        }
        return results;
    }
    inline void add_rect(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {  //create walls (this part doesn't work atm)
        for (int x = x1; x < x2; ++x) {
            for (int y = y1; y < y2; ++y) {
                walls.insert(Graph::Location{ x, y });
            }
        }
    }
};

template<typename T>
array<Graph::Location, 4> Graph::DIRS{ Graph::Location{ 1, 0 }, Graph::Location{ 0, -1 }, Graph::Location{ -1, 0 }, Graph::Location{ 0, 1 } };

template<typename T>
inline int heuristic(Graph::Location a, Graph::Location b) {    //Manhattan distance
    int x1, y1, x2, y2;
    tie(x1, y1) = a;
    tie(x2, y2) = b;
    return abs(x1 - x2) + abs(y1 - y2);
}

template<typename T, typename Number = int>
struct PriorityQueue {
    typedef pair<Number, T> PQElement;
    priority_queue<PQElement, vector<PQElement>,
        std::greater<PQElement >> elements;

    inline bool empty() { return elements.empty(); }

    inline void put(T item, Number priority) {
        elements.emplace(priority, item);
    }

    inline T get() {
        T best_item = elements.top().second;
        elements.pop();
        return best_item;
    }
};

template<typename Graph>
void a_star_search
(Graph graph,
typename Graph::Location start,
typename Graph::Location goal,
unordered_map<typename Graph::Location, typename Graph::Location>& came_from,
unordered_map<typename Graph::Location, int>& cost_so_far)
{
    typedef typename Graph::Location Location;
    PriorityQueue<Location> frontier;   //possible next locations
    frontier.put(start, 0);

    came_from[start] = start;
    cost_so_far[start] = 0;

    while (!frontier.empty()) {
        auto current = frontier.get();  //get next location from frontier

        if (current == goal) {
            break;
        }

        for (auto next : graph.neighbors(current)) {
            int new_cost = cost_so_far[current] + graph.cost(current, next);
            if (!cost_so_far.count(next) || new_cost < cost_so_far[next]) {
                cost_so_far[next] = new_cost;
                int priority = new_cost + heuristic(next, goal);
                frontier.put(next, priority);
                came_from[next] = current;
            }
        }
    }
}

template<typename T>
void draw_grid(const Graph& graph, int field_width,
    unordered_map<typename Graph::Location, int>* distances = nullptr,
    unordered_map<typename Graph::Location, typename Graph::Location>* point_to = nullptr,
    vector<typename Graph::Location>* path = nullptr) {
    for (int y = 0; y != graph.height; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x != graph.width; ++x) {
            typename Graph::Location id{ x, y };
            std::cout << std::left << std::setw(field_width);
            if (graph.walls.count(id)) {
                std::cout << string(field_width, 'X');
            }
            else {
                cout << '.';
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Basically these are my unordered_map's:

```
unordered_map<Location, Location>
unordered_map<Location,Location>*
unordered_map<Location,int>
unordered_map<Location,int>*
```

where the type Location is basically an (x,y) coordinate. If I used a map the only difference is the O(log n) and the O(1) lookup time, right? I wouldn't have to create a hash function, from what I've read about maps. Could you guys help me to decide whether to use a map or an unordered_map (not all of it, just what I need to know), and what I would change to use either one? Thanks!